# Waveshare display acting wierd

Tags: pi-3b+, power, hdmi, display, video

I am using a waveshare 7inch display it was working well but today when i connexted it to raspberry pi the output is unexpected

[image]

Please help me out
Thanks in advance

Comment: any lnk to the display? what do you expect to see?

Comment: `output is unexpected` ... that is meaningless ... only you know what it means exactly

Comment: wierd isn't a word (and I would be expecting an adverb in the context)